# SQLServer concat problem inside Spring Data @Query

Tags: sql-server, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have this query below that is working fine on MySql and Oracle but fail on SQLServer:

```
@Query("SELECT ca FROM ContextAccess ca " + "LEFT JOIN UserContextAccess uca on ca.id = uca.id " +
        "LEFT JOIN RegularUserInfo rui on rui.user = uca.user " +
        "WHERE ca.context = :context and (COALESCE(:roles, null) is null or ca.role in (:roles)) " +
        "AND (:name is null or ca.accessType='GROUP' or CONCAT(rui.firstName,' ',rui.lastName) like CONCAT(:name,'%') " +
        "or CONCAT(rui.lastName,' ',rui.firstName) like CONCAT(:name,'%'))")
```

I have this stacktrace:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The data types varbinary and varchar are incompatible in the add operator.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1624)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:594)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:524)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7194)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2979)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:248)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:223)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:446)
```

the problem come from `CONCAT(:name,'%')` 
I can solve it by using '+' operator like this `:name + '%'` but after it's not working on Oracle

Do you have an idea to solve this problem ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CONCAT(:name,\"%\")`

The double-quote character has to be escaped with a backslash in a Java string literal.